# Facebook Messenger - Why can't sync be enabled?

Tags: applications, sync, facebook-messenger, samsung-one-ui

Until recently I was using Messanger Lite, but it was moved to Facebook Lite, so I started using "classic" Messenger.

Unfortunately, it doesn't work well. However, the reason is simple. In **Settings -> Accounts and backup -> Manage accounts ->** Messenger synchronization is not enabled.

[image]

So it would be enough to enable it, but I don't know how to do it (after clicking on it, nothing is displayed unlike, for example, a Google account)

Do you know how to solve this please?

Thank you

PS. [Samsung Galaxy A14](https://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_a14-12151.php) - Android 13 (One UI 5.1)